# Count words in texts that are NOT in a given dictionary

Tags: r, nlp, word-count, quanteda

How can I find and count words that are NOT in a given dictionary?

The example below counts every time specific dictionary words (clouds and storms) appear in the text.

```
library("quanteda")
txt <- "Forty-four Americans have now taken the presidential oath. The words have been spoken during rising tides of prosperity and the still waters of peace. Yet, every so often the oath is taken amidst gathering clouds and raging storms. At these moments, America has carried on not simply because of the skill or vision of those in high office, but because We the People have remained faithful to the ideals of our forbearers, and true to our founding documents."   
mydict <- dictionary(list(all_terms = c("clouds", "storms")))
dfmat <- tokens(txt) %>%
  tokens_select(mydict) %>%
  dfm()
dfmat
```

The output:

```
docs    clouds storms
  text1      1      1
```

How can I instead generate a count of all words that are NOT in the dictionary (clouds/storms)? Ideally with stopwords excluded.

E.g., desired output:

```
docs    Forty-four Americans ...
  text1      1      1
```

Comment: This is actually NOT a reproducible example, not unless you provide us with the 'data_corpus_inaugural' and the 'data_dictionary_lsd_2015' objects

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you wish as an answer here. What do you want in your output dfm? All of the non-dictionary matches combined in `OTHER`, or the non-dictionary matches as features in your final dfm? And as in the example above, do you want these for each dictionary key, or combined?

Comment: Thanks guys I edited my question, should be clearer now, hopefully!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you check the help file for tokens_select (run `?tokens_select`) you can see that the third argument is `selection`. The default value is `"keep"`, yet what you want is `"remove"`. Since this is a common thing to do, there is also a dedicated `tokens_remove` command, which I use below to to remove stopwords.

```r
dfmat <- tokens(txt) %>%
  tokens_select(mydict, selection = "remove") %>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords::stopwords(language = "en")) %>% 
  dfm()
dfmat
#> Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 38 features (0.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>        features
#> docs    forty-four americans now taken presidential oath . words spoken rising
#>   text1          1         1   1     2            1    2 4     1      1      1
#> [ reached max_nfeat ... 28 more features ]
```

I think this is what you are trying to do.

<sup>Created on 2021-12-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

this is kinda a case example a use of the setdiff() function.  Here is an example of how to extract the words used by Obama (in $2013-Obama) not used by Biden (in $2021-Biden) from your example:

```
diff <- setdiff(toks[[1]], toks[[3]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand. Can you demonstrate it, using my example?